# How to make Jquery execute a function which its name is composed by a word and a variable?

Tags: jquery, variables

I have 3 functions saved into variables : f1,f2,f3. I have 3 list-items,only one of them has class "active", if you click on one of them it will have this class "active".

When i click a button, and, for example, the 2nd list-item has class "active" i need to activate function f3. I saved into a variable "x" the number of the list-item which has the class. So i need to activate the function $("f"+(x+1)).

Also if the number of li equals with the functions number(the last li), i need to execute the first function, f1.

```
<button>Click</button>

<ul>
    <li data-number="1" class="active">First</li>
    <li data-number="2">Second</li>
    <li data-number="3">Third</li>
</ul>
```

.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var f1 = function f1() {console.log("f1");};
    var f2 = function f2() {console.log("f2");};
    var f3 = function f3() {console.log("f3");};

    var functions = [f1, f2, f3];

    // add or remove the "active" class
    $("li").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings("li").removeClass("active");
    });

    // when the button is clicked
    $("button").click(function () {
        var x = $("ul").find("li.active").data("number");

        if (x = functions.length) {
            $(f1);
        } else {
            $("f" + (x + 1)); //also it doesn't work $(f+(x+1))
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/alex111kira/oqr7e1zu/7/)

Comment: should `if (x = functions.length) {` be `if (x == functions.length) {` - note `==` vs `=`

Comment: Why are you wrapping your functions with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

```
var functions = {
  f1: function () { console.log("f1"); },
  f2: function () { console.log("f2"); },
  f3: function () { console.log("f3"); }
}

// ...
var x = $("ul").find("li.active").data("number");
functions["f" + x]();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// wrap functions within an Object
var fns = {
    f1: function () {
        console.log("f1");
    },
    f2: function () {
        console.log("f2");
    },
    f3: function f3() {
        console.log("f3");
    }
};

// add or remove the "active" class
$("li").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings("li").removeClass("active");
});

// when the button is clicked
$("button").click(function () {

    var x = $("ul").find("li.active").data("number");

    // Object.keys(fns).length is getting fns length
    if (x == Object.keys(fns).length) {
        fns.f1();
    } else {
        // calling specific function from fns
        fnx['f'+ x]();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting functions as items within an array , calling function at `$(this).data().number` index within array , or index `0` on click of `li`

```js
$(function() {

  var fns = [
    function f1() {
      console.log("f1");
    },
    function f2() {
      console.log("f2");
    },
    function f3() {
      console.log("f3");
    }
  ];

  var fn;

  $("li").click(function() {
    fn = fns[$(this).data().number];
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings("li").removeClass("active");
  });

  $("button").click(function(e, n) {
    fn ? fn() : fns[n || 0]();
  }).trigger("click", [1]);

});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button>Click</button>
<ul>
  <li data-number="1" class="active">First</li>
  <li data-number="2">Second</li>
  <li data-number="3">Third</li>
</ul>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/oqr7e1zu/9/

Comment: Thank you, but only when i click the button, not the li. I need something like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alex111kira/oqr7e1zu/8/). I used your code, but something is a little bit wrong.

Comment: @AlexB. Try defining variable `fn` outside of `$("li").click()` , moving `$("button").click(function() {})` after `$("li").click(function() {})` to prevent multiple `click` events being attached to `button` element ; trigger `click` on `button` to initiate `fn` ,  `fns` . See updated post